# bootstrap nav bar collapse issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The site i am developing is driving me crazy. I got a media query to collapse the navbar but i dont know exactly how to change the button. The collapse also does not display correctly. Tried to change navhar height to compensate and tried using position:relative but no luck.

HTML

```
<div class="containter-fluid" id="full-size-container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
          Menu
        </button>
      </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
          <li><a href="home-page.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="superstars.html">Superstars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
          <li><a href="about-us.html">About </a></li>
          <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>



<div class="jumbotron">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/banner1.jpg" alt="banner1">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="banner2">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/banner3.jpg" alt="banner3">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/banner4.jpg" alt="banner4">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
body{
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    height: auto;
}


.carousel .item {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    height: none;
    width:  100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
          transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

.jumbotron{
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom: 00px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav{
    margin-left: 80px;
}
ul li{
    position:relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 00px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1170px){

    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-brand{
        height:;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid ;
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
        position: relative;
        top: -10px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-brand > button{
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
        right: 50px;
    }

}
.navbar-brand > img{
    left: 30px;
    height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
    width:auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;

}

#navbar {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: blue;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul li a{
    color: blue;
}

#navbar .navbar-toggle{
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-color: white;
    }

#navbar .navbar-toggle:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#navbar .navbar-toggle .glyphicon{
    color:white;
}
#navbar .navbar-toggle:hover .glyphicon{
    color:white;
}
```

Issue is:

> Collapse navbar does not show above the carousel
>   Collapse navbar does not start from the navbar (you can see carousel slide between collapse button and navbar start)
>   Menu button must be 1.2x bigger

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @RenierSwart, could you duplicate this in a snippet or JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally because you specified a height for the `navbar` which has a default value of `min-height: 50px` so when under 768px it creates the background for the mobile navigation links. By setting a fixed height it can no longer function as it's meant to. Try using padding to change the height of the nav.

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Working Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  height: auto;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-toggle .glyphicon {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover .glyphicon {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand > img {
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 25px 0;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-left,
  .navbar .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    margin: 25px 0 -12.5px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="containter-fluid" id="full-size-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span> Menu
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f00" alt="LOGO">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
        <li><a href="home-page.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="superstars.html">Superstars</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shows</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about-us.html">About </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Social</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

without a fiddle/snippet to test your code, one observation that you can try is `clearfix`.

add the below code above the `jumbotron` div, below the end `</nav>`

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```